# Where is the null termination bug?

Tags: c, string, null

I am going over this exercise (full source code):
http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex29.html

A part of the code is shown below:

```
int uppercase(const char *msg)
{
    int i = 0;

    // BUG: \0 termination problems
    for(i = 0; msg[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        printf("%c", toupper(msg[i]));
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The author comments that there is a bug. Later his instruction says:

> Were you paying attention to the bad code I have in the libex29.c functions? See how, even though I use a for-loop they still check for '\0' endings? Fix this so the functions always take a length for the string to work with inside the function.

However, I dont see the bug here. Since the loop will terminate if there is a null character.

Anyone else sees a problem here?

Comment: Um, do you *understand* what a null termination bug is? Because this is the very definition of one?

Comment: "Since the loop will terminate if there is a null character. " Yes, but what if there **isn't**?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, if there isn't the string haven't finish. What is the suggested way of doing it?

Comment: @MarcusMüller You should post that (and an explanation, of course) as an answer.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, do you mean someone gives a string without null termination? In that case, how do one determine the string is terminated?

Comment: Imagine you want to drive from Washington, DC to Richmond, so you get on Interstate 95 and head south, looking for the exit sign for Richmond. Unfortunately, the sign was removed by vandals and so you just keep on going, eventually driving over a cliff in Florida and ending up in the Caribbean.

Comment: Read the quote again, about modifying the function to take a *length*. However, don't just use the length alone, just like you should not use the terminator character check alone. Use *both*.

Comment: Sure. Do you mean a fix length need to be given?

Comment: Also note that the bug isn't necessarily in the function you show. If the code is documented to take a zero-terminated string as argument, and the caller passes a string that is not zero-terminated then the bug is with the caller.

Comment: use `putc` instead of `printf`, you can also change `msg[i] != '\0'` to `msg[i]`. Try this: `for (i = 0; msg[i] && i < N; i++) {` where `N` is the maximum number of characters `msg` can have. Use `if (!msg) return ...;` to avoid reading from memory address 0.

Comment: Well .... passing a length can reduce the chances of a caller causing a bug by passing bad data to the function, because it forces the programmer to think both about what the pointer is and what the corresponding length is.   It doesn't PREVENT the caller introducing bugs though - since it relies on the caller computing the length correctly.  The function can't compute the length, given only a pointer, so needs to be passed the length.   But the caller can still introduce a bug by passing a pair (`msg` and `length`) that, in combination, are bad.

Comment: @DombiSzabolcs: Using `printf` rather than `putc` is a bit clumsy, but it's not incorrect. Replacing `msg[i] != '\0'` by `msg[i]` makes no difference (except that, in my opinion, `msg[i] != '\0'` is clearer).

Comment: I don't see how calling it with a length parameter would be any safer. It doesn't prevent caller's bugs, as you can pass the wrong length just as easy. It just duplicates information and encourages wrong API usage, and tends to hide programming errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only "bug" is that the function's behavior and requirements are not clearly documented.

If the documentation stated that the argument must be a valid pointer to a string (which by definition must be null-terminated), then the function is correct as far as I can tell (well, almost -- see below), and it is entirely the caller's responsibility to pass a correct argument. The C standard library is full of string functions that behave this way.

If the documentation stated that the function itself is responsible for checking for a valid argument, then it needs to state (1) exactly what the requirements are, and (2) exactly how the function should behave given an invalid argument.

It can check for `msg == NULL` easily enough -- but then you have to specify what it should do when that happens.

It can check for the presence of a `'\0'` terminator within the first N characters -- but then you have to specify the value of N somehow (apparently the author expects an added length parameter) *and* you have to say how the function should behave when that happens.

It cannot check for an invalid non-null argument. For example, a caller might pass a pointer that hasn't been initialized, or that has been passed to `free()`. There is no portable (and likely no non-portable) way for the function to check for that kind of error.

If the function is modified to take a length argument (which is a perfectly reasonable change that makes the function safer to use), then it still cannot check for all possible error conditions. A caller could pass a length argument that doesn't match the length of the actual array. It's still the caller's responsibility to call `tolower` correctly.

A specification for a function is a *contract* between the caller and the callee. Both sides must satisfy the specification. In the absence of any such specification (beyond the function declaration, which gives us some information but not enough), it's very difficult to say that the function has a "bug".

A minor point: I actually did find what is *probably* a genuine bug in the function. The `toupper()` function takes an argument of type `int`, whose value must be either equal to `EOF` or in the range `0` to `UCHAR_MAX`. If plain `char` is signed by default, then it's possible to have a valid `char` value that is negative and unequal to `EOF`. The result is undefined behavior. The fix for that is to cast the argument to `unsigned char`:

```
printf("%c", toupper((unsigned char)msg[i]));
```

(The `EOF` special case is not relevant here.)

Now that might not be an actual bug. In the absence of any specification, we might assume that the string should only contain characters with non-negative values. But such a restriction should be stated explicitly.

There's also a potential portability issue: depending on the system, it might be possible to have a string longer than `INT_MAX` bytes. Making `i` a `size_t` rather than an `int` would avoid that (admittedly unlikely) problem. Again, this might be considered an implicit restriction -- but such restrictions should be made explicit whenever possible.

Finally, the function is defined to return an `int` result, but it always returns `0`. It could make sense to use the return value as an error indicator. A common convention is to return `0` for success, non-zero for failure. If this version of the function is intended as the basis for an improved version that does more error checking, returning an `int` result is reasonable.  But then there should be a specification of what that result means.

Comment: Documentation, exactly. UV

Comment: like your comprehensive answer

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems:

The "string" might not be null-terminated.

The input pointer `msg` might be `NULL`.

You get around the first issue by either fixing it (passing the length) or writing clear documentation, along the lines of the c standard library functions. I prefer the latter since computing the length prior to your calling the function could result in two traversals of the string which is clumsy.

You should guard against the second problem using an if block or similar construct.

Comment: I like the cases you listed. But how would you fix the bug?

Comment: Could you provide a sample for your prefer fix for the first one? The second fix is quite obvious. passing length is easy to understand. But what do you mean by clear documentation?

Comment: @elixir `for(i = 0; (msg[i] != '\0')&&(i < max_i); i++)`, where `max_i` is defined… There's no way to know the length of "string" unless null-terminated or explicitly passed. You can pass `i_max` as maximum allowed length of the array member, which safeguards against reading past boundaries. Else it depends on who/what populates the array and if it has been done correctly.